# Change Security & Privacy setting from terminal

Tags: macos, security

I need to enable the "Require an administrator password to access locked preferences" on about a dozen Macs. I would like to do it from ARD as a unix command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using AppleScript :

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell security preferences
    set properties to {require password to unlock:true}
    end tell
end tell
```

You can call the Applescript code using the `osascript` command.